why does docker compose still create an implicit network
services:
  echo:
    image: busybox
    command: echo 7

  server:
    build: .
    command: server 0.0.0.0:8000
    healthcheck:
      test: /app/compose-tinker poke localhost:8000
      interval: 1s
      retries: 10

  client:
    build: .
    command: client server:8000
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on: 
      server:
        condition: service_healthy

networks:
  my_network: {}

here’s my compose file. notice that the toplevel networks declares a my_network network and none of the services is connected to it
$ docker compose -f compose-7.yaml build --no-cache
$ docker compose -f compose-7.yaml up              
[+] Running 4/0
 ✔ Network compose-tinker_default     Created                                                        0.0s 
 ✔ Container compose-tinker-server-1  Created                                                        0.0s 
 ✔ Container compose-tinker-echo-1    Created                                                        0.0s 
 ✔ Container compose-tinker-client-1  Created                                                        0.0s 
$ docker compose -f compose-7.yaml down
[+] Running 4/0
 ✔ Container compose-tinker-client-1  Removed                                                        0.0s 
 ✔ Container compose-tinker-echo-1    Removed                                                        0.0s 
 ✔ Container compose-tinker-server-1  Removed                                                        0.0s 
 ✔ Network compose-tinker_default     Removed

yet docker compose still creates a compose-tinker_default network and puts all services on it; they communicate with each other just fine. what gives? i was expecting all containers to be isolated. but docker creates an implicit default network even though i’ve explicitly defined a custom network and puts all services on it. is this supposed to happen and how do i isolate all containers?

This is supposed to happen. the default docker network is an implicit definition and defining another network does not change or alter the default network in any way. The services that do not declare explicit networks continue to use their implicit network configurations.
To prevent the implicit network attachments use network_mode
services:
  hello:
    image: nginx
    network_mode: bridge


If you really want to use a custom network, you also need a networks: blocks on each service and explicitly attach each service to the non-default network.
services:
  server:
    networks:       # <-- missing from your example
      - my_network  # <--
networks:
  my_network:

For almost all applications running in Compose, this is unnecessary, though.  If you delete all of the networks: block in the file, including the top-level networks:, as you note in the question, Compose will create a network named default (as though you had top-level networks: {default:}) and attach each service to it (as though they had networks: [default]).  This is exactly the same as the setup you're trying for except that the network name is different, but that name isn't visible to the application at all.
